# Onclick event not firing from individual cell click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to fire an onclick event for whenever an individual cell in my gridview is clicked, but it is not calling the function. I also tried adding ("onclick", "Btn_AddNewSite_Click(sender, e)") and that did not work either. Any pointers in the right direction would be great.

```
e.Row.Cells[column].Attributes.Add("onclick", "Btn_AddNewSite_Click()");

protected void Btn_AddNewSite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModalPopupExtender1.PopupControlID = "Panel1";
    ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by making sure that `Btn_AddNewSite` is a LinkButton.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Btn_AddNewSite" runat="server" OnClick="Btn_AddNewSite_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then you can use the javascript code that handles the LinkButton click in the Cell by using it's UniqueID.

```
e.Row.Cells[column].Attributes.Add("onclick", "__doPostBack('" + Btn_AddNewSite.UniqueID + "', '')");
```

Comment: Yes it does. Where and when are you adding the attribute?

Comment: I added the asp link button code right before I have my asp gridview code. And then I copied the exact line you have for e.Row.Cells[column].......... and it did not fire the function call, but it refreshed the page.

Comment: Does the button have the correct `OnClick` event? If not it will indeed just refresh the page.

Comment: I fixed it. I had another button name with the same ID. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`e.Row.Cells[column].Attributes.Add("onclick", "Btn_AddNewSite_Click()");`

This will add a HTML attribute to the cell which means whenever you click the cell in the browser the browser will look for a JavaScript function called "Btn_AddNewSite_Click" which obviously is not there as this is a server side .NET function.