# ASP gridview click cell event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I usually do not code in ASP.NET but after several years, I made a project for ordering lunch. 
I created the gridview and dynamically filled the cells and display text. it is like some "clickable maps".
varianta.aspx, has below code:

```
gridMain.Rows[iRow].Cells[iColumn].Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.location='varianta.aspx?den=" + dayJL + "&c_j_listek=" + ic_j_listek + "&c_druh_var_dieta=" + den.C_DRUH_VAR_DIETA + "';")
```

and in page's load in condition for postback I get the parameters from querystring and I save the changes and load the grid with changes. It works.

But now, they want the app to use for internet. And they doesn't like querystring,  so I would like to pass the parameters in another way.
I found this solution, but it is maybe only for some button.

```
gridMain.Rows[iRadek].Cells[iSloupec].Attributes.Add("onclick", "Link_Click");
gridMain.Rows[iRadek].Cells[iSloupec].Attributes.Add("CommandArgument", 
    denJL.ToString()+"#"+ic_j_listek.ToString()+"#"+den.C_DRUH_VAR_DIETA.ToString());
```

Have any idea and tips how to solve it?
Thanks for your reply
Jan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Onclick event not firing from individual cell click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520234/onclick-event-not-firing-from-individual-cell-click)

Comment: thank you, but is it necessary to use the link button? i read something about this soluiton, but is it some solution without link button? only clicking in cell without button and passing hides parametres.